# Android. To connect to secundary database in other path

Tags: android, database

I have an app working with a single local sqllite database in data/data/com.endel.psicotest/databases/psico.db

but I'm trying to connect to a secundary and old db in /data/data/com.example.psicotestv1/databases/

but when I had tried SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase(); in my DataBaseHelper_OLD **return me the first database** :(

```
public DBMain_OLD(Context contexto) {
    super(contexto, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    //Calculamos la ruta de la base de datos
    File file = new File(contexto.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
    DB_PATH_OLD = "data/data/com.example.psicotest3/databases/";
    this.context  = contexto;
}
```

my secundary constructor with the DB_PATH_OLD

```
DataBaseHelper_OLD myDbHelper_OLD = new DataBaseHelper_OLD(contexto);
    Item item_OLD = myDbHelper_OLD.GetItemId(idPregunta);
```

I got the value of first database :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a DB between 2 apps, you will need to implement a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). You can't share a simple database because an application normally can't access other applications' folders. (I said normally because apps with roots access can). And this is why when you call `SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();` you only get the DB from your app.

[Content Provider Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)